# How check whether variable have already been watched in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This code reacts on variable `my_var` changes in scope:

```
    $scope.$watch('my_var', function () {
        //do somethins
    });
```

Is there a way to check whether `my_var` is being watched or not? E.g. have somebody already called `$scope.$watch` function on `my_var` or not?

Comment: you can fire an event if a `variable` is watched and you can recieve the same somewhere else

Comment: You can check using $scope.$$watchers. It will list all the watchers applied on your scope variables

Answer (score 1):

You can simply list all of your watchers and check if your variable has a watcher. I don't think there are any other ways to check if `$scope.$watch` already applied on it.

Here is the code that you can paste even in your console to check your watchers:

```js
function getWatchers(root) {
  root = angular.element(root || document.documentElement);
  var watcherCount = 0;

  function getElemWatchers(element) {
    var isolateWatchers = getWatchersFromScope(element.data().$isolateScope);
    var scopeWatchers = getWatchersFromScope(element.data().$scope);
    var watchers = scopeWatchers.concat(isolateWatchers);
    angular.forEach(element.children(), function(childElement) {
      watchers = watchers.concat(getElemWatchers(angular.element(childElement)));
    });
    return watchers;
  }

  function getWatchersFromScope(scope) {
    if (scope) {
      return scope.$$watchers || [];
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }
  return getElemWatchers(root);
}

console.log(getWatchers())
// this prints the array of watchers, e.g:
// [ {fn: ƒ, last: "my_var", get: ƒ, exp: ƒ, eq: false} ]
```

The code is taken from ["Watching your AngularJS Watchers"](https://medium.com/@kentcdodds/counting-angularjs-watchers-11c5134dc2ef) by *Kent C. Dodds*

(The code was modified to print watchers, instead of just displaying how many are used (*array length*), so be prepared if you have more that 1000+ watchers)

Answer (score 1):

This may help.

```
let myVar = $scope.my_var;
Object.defineProperty($scope, 'my_var', {
    get: function() {
        console.log('Someone called me');
        return myVar;
    },
    set: function(val) {
        myVar  = val;
    }
});
$scope.$apply();
```

If this variable is being watched - you will see something in log. (Of course you may have some access from your js code, but you can debug ... Also this should be $scope, where variable is actuall defined)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
function isWatched($scope, ref) {
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.$$watchers.length; i++) {
        const w = $scope.$$watchers[i];
        if (w && w.exp === ref)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$scope.$watch('my_var', function () {
    //do somethins
});

var result = isWatched($scope, 'my_var');
```